# How to get value from two dimentional Selection Box using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a selection box with the same Id and Name like the one below:

```
 <input id="primary_employee_address[country_code]" name ="primary_employee_address[country_code]"
```

Now if i do

```
document.getElementById( 'primary_employee_address[country_code]' ).value
```

I am getting the desired result. However if i try

```
jQuery( '#primary_employee_address[country_code]' ).val());
```

I am always getting the result "undefined". How can i solve the same issue. Any help shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the selector with with `\\` if it contains characters that have significance to the jQuery selector engine;

```
$('#primary_employee_address\\[country_code\\]')...
```

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly with jQuery documentation `[]` are used to define some filters for your selection, so I think jQuery is trying to get you the element with id `primary_emplyee_address` having the attribute `country_code` which not exists.

Read more about this on [jQuery selectors documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

yes boss...

JQuery uses this square box representation to select elements based on the attributes which where defined  in between these square brackets.

like :

$('input[type=checkbox][name=question]')

Better use escape sequences "\" before those brackets ([ as \[ and ] as \]) to let JQuery interpret your control id